# Circular List, Removing Node

Tags: c++, debugging

I have a node like this:

```
Node(T data, Node *next, Node *prev)
{
    this->data = data;
    this->next = next;
    this->prev = prev;
};
```

My remove look like, I am looping over and trying to iterate every item and then delete if it's the correct one...

```
bool remove(const T& item) // requires == operator of item
{
    if (current == nullptr)
    {
        throw string("Can't remove from empty list!");
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < nrOfNodes; i++)
    {
        Node *iterator = current->prev;
        if (iterator->next->data == item)
        {
            Node* iteratorAfter = iterator->next->next;
            iteratorAfter->prev = iterator;

            delete iterator->next;

            iterator->next = iteratorAfter;

            return true;
        }

        iterator = iterator->next;
    }

    return false;
};
```

However, it gives me:

> Unhandled exception at 0x0F5D31CA (msvcr120d.dll) in Upp2.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xFEEEFEEE.

But I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong...

Comment: What is the result when you used a debugger?

Comment: You're doing several things wrong. You're using too much indirection, neglecting to use a debugger or diagnostic output, and not giving us a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell what you are doing wrong, as you haven't showed the full code involved in this program. For example, the declaration and definition of the variable 'current' is missing.
Please note that 'current' is not updated in the 'remove' function. So, even if it has a valid value at the entry to this function, assuming that number of nodes in the list is at least 2, the function will probably segfault on the first line of the for loop. This will happen on the second iteration of the loop because of the delete that happened in the previous iteration on the 3'rd line of the if block within the for loop.